# Keyboard layout for math

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-layout, unicode, latex

I usually need to write math with LaTeX, and after seeing this question: [Entering unicode math symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110042/entering-unicode-math-symbols-into-latex-direct-from-keyboard-on-a-mac). I came here with some small questions.

I find that not perfectly comfortable, and I was wondering if there is a way in which I could tell the system to differentiate between the left and right <kbd>alt ⌥</kbd>. So I could have much more symbols within one *letter*.

And, the another question is if there is a way I could turn the <kbd>caps lock ⇪</kbd> into a different key (with the same use as <kbd>alt ⌥</kbd>, but the system should differentiate them). In this way I could use, for instance,

- <kbd>caps lock ⇪</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to get the greek letters (in this case the letter delta `δ`), and
- <kbd>alt ⌥</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to get some math symbol of my decision (in this case the *partial differential symbol* `∂`).

This is not a great example, but more or less self explaining. Of course then <kbd>caps lock ⇪</kbd> shouldn't be a turn on/turn off button. It should be *turned on* ONLY when pressed (exactly like <kbd>alt ⌥</kbd>).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In keylayout files `option` is left (or either) option and `rightOption` is right option. `leftOption` results in an error. Right modifier keys have been registered as left modifier keys on all keyboards I have tested with though. So for example this would also make right option + a insert α:

```
<modifierMap id="commonModifiers" defaultIndex="0">
    <keyMapSelect mapIndex="0">
        <modifier keys="option"/>
    </keyMapSelect>
    <keyMapSelect mapIndex="1">
        <modifier keys="rightOption"/>
    </keyMapSelect>
</modifierMap>
<keyMapSet id="ANSI">
    <keyMap index="0">
        <key code="0" output="α"/> <!-- key code 0 is QWERTY a -->
    </keyMap>
    <keyMap index="1">
        <key code="0" output="β"/>
    </keyMap>
</keyMapSet>
```

One workaround is to add a keymap with modifier keys like `anyControl anyOption anyShift anyCommand` and then remap right option with [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

`<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_R, KeyCode::OPTION_L, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L | ModifierFlag::OPTION_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L | ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>`

Caps lock can also be used as a fifth modifier key in keylayout files. You can use KeyRemap4MacBook to change another key to a holdable caps lock:

`<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_R, Option::KEYTOKEY_BEFORE_KEYDOWN, KeyCode::CAPSLOCK, Option::KEYTOKEY_AFTER_KEYUP, KeyCode::CAPSLOCK</autogen>`

Or use PCKeyboardHack to change caps lock to something like F19 and then remap F19 to a holdable caps lock. The "Pass-Through Caps Lock LED Status" setting disables the caps lock light on some keyboards.

See http://lri.me/osx.html for more information about custom keyboard layouts and KeyRemap4MacBook.

Other options:

- Change your main keyboard layout to Unicode Hex Input and for example remap right option + a to option+`03b2`. See [this blog post](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2012/10/a-modern-space-cadet/) and [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41657/use-option-arrows-with-unicode-hex-input).
- Use [DefaultKeyBinding.dict](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35386/how-to-create-shortcut-to-insert-specific-special-character/37232#37232).
- Import abbreviations used for [HTML entities](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=fAyVyGhy) or LaTeX character commands to TextExpander.

Comment: This is great. I will look further in a few hours. By the way, my intention was not to install any extra software. So I will try with the first part and wait to some solving for the second (caps lock related). If nothing comes I will see if that works. Thank you!